# Can SetDelayed (:=) be compiled?

Tags: function-construction, compile

Is it possible to put an `If` statement as below within a compile (see below)? I received a warning about `SetDelayed`.

```
  eef = Compile[{{μ, _Real}, {NNN, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{NN = NNN}, 
     kd[m_, n_] := If[m == n, 1, 0];
     cosfun[m_, n_] := 
       If[m == n, 
          0, 
          (1 - Cos[(m + n) π])/( (m + n) π) 
          + ((Cos[(m - n) π] - 1)/( (m - n) π))
       ];

      mm = Table[kd[m, n] (MM - B2 k k - B1 (m Pi/L)^2),  
              {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}];
      kz = Table[cosfun[m, n] (-I A2 m Pi/L), {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}];
      kxM = Table[kd[m, n] A1 k, {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}];
      μM = Table[kd[m, n] μ, {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}];

      HH = ArrayFlatten[{
             {μM + mm, 0 mm, kz, kxM}, 
             {0 mm, μM + mm, kxM, -kz}, 
             {kz, kxM, μM - mm, 0 mm}, 
             {kxM, -kz, 0 mm, μM - mm}
           }];

      ees = Table[Eigenvalues[HH], {k, -.1, .1, .01}]

     ] (* End Module  *)
    ]  (* End Compile *)
```

where `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2`, and `MM` are global variables.

Comment: It would help to have some test values for your global variables. Also, $L$ is also a global variable, I think.

Comment: You can define `cosfun` and `kd` (why redefine `KroneckerDelta`?) before with compile and use them in your compiled function without problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Compile` can't handle `SetDelayed`.

In your specific case, you might be able to avoid the need for `SetDelayed` altogether through the use of `Boole`.

`kd[m_, n_] :=If[m == n, 1, 0]` can be replaced by `Boole[n==m]`. (or as FJRA pointed out in comments, by `KroneckerDelta`.)

```
cosfun[m_, n_] := 
 If[m == n, 0, (1 - Cos[(m + n) π])/((m + n) π) + 
  ((Cos[(m - n) π] - 1)/((m - n) π))]
```

can be replaced by

```
Boole[m == n] (1 - Cos[(m + n) π])/((m +  n) π) + 
 ((Cos[(m - n) π] - 1)/((m - n) π)) (-I A2 m Pi/L)
```

Giving

```
eenew = Compile[{{μ, _Real}, {NNN, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{NN = NNN}, (* do you even need this placeholder for the input? *)
   mm = Table[Boole[m == n] (MM - B2 k k - B1 (m Pi/L)^2), {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}]; 
   kz =  Table[Boole[m != n] (1 -  Cos[(m + n) π])/((m + n) π) + 
     ((Cos[(m - n) π] - 1)/((m - n) π)) (-I A2 m Pi/L), 
     {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}]; 
   kxM =   Table[Boole[m == n] A1 k, {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}]; 
  μM = Table[Boole[m == n] μ, {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}]; 
   HH =    ArrayFlatten[{{μM + mm, 0 mm, kz, kxM}, 
      {0 mm, μM + mm, kxM, -kz}, {kz, kxM, μM - mm,0 mm}, 
      {kxM, -kz, 0 mm, μM - mm}}]; 
  ees = Table[Eigenvalues[HH], {k, -.1, .1, .01}]]]
```

What is `k` for in this last line? There is no way for the iterator to matter for `HH`.

This doesn't give the error involving `SetDelayed` anymore.

Comment: The `Indeterminate` expression you were getting had to do with letting $m \to n$ in `kz`. I corrected your code, so this won't happen.

Comment: Note that `SetDelayed` is included in this list of compilable functions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/219

Answer (score 8):

Since your matrices are all of the same size, I would construct them in a different manner entirely, and not use `SetDelayed` at all.

Starting with `mm`, `kxm`, and `μM`, I would note that they are all diagonal, and except for `mm`, they are all multiples of the identity matrix. So, I would use this instead,

```
kxm = A1 k IdentityMatrix[NN];
μM = μ IdentityMatrix[NN];
```

or, even

```
{kxm, μM} = {A1 k #, μ #}& @ IdentityMatrix[3];
```

and for `mm` which depends on the position in the diagonal

```
mm = DiagonalMatrix[MM - B2 k k - B1 (Range[NN] Pi/L)^2];
```

If you have not encountered it before, the construction of `mm` may seem a little odd, but it relies on the fact that some mathematical operations are vectorizable in Mathematica, e.g. `q {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}^2` returns

```
{q, 4 q, 9 q, 25 q}
```

Also, [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiagonalMatrix.html) is a built-in function for constructing just this type of matrix, and it is [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/52) (as is `Range`, too).

For `kxm`, I would embed you `If` statement directly in `Table`, as follows

```
kxM =  
 Table[
  If[m == n, 0, 
   (-2 n + (m + n) Cos[(m - n)Pi] + (-m + n) Cos[(m + n) Pi])/((m^2 - n^2)Pi^2),
  {m, 1, NN}, {n, 1, NN}
 ];
```

Lastly, `ArrayFlatten` has the property that you can use scalars in place of constant matrices, provided that there is at least one matrix in both the same row and column that Mathematica can use to determine the size from.  For example,

```
 ArrayFlatten[{{IdentityMatrix[2], 5},{b^2, IdentityMatrix[2]}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 5, 5}, {0, 1, 5, 5}, {b^2, b^2, 1, 0}, {b^2, b^2, 0, 1}}
> ```

but this the size of the `c` block in this matrix can not be determined to be anything but $1 \times 1$,

```
ArrayFlatten[{{IdentityMatrix[3], 5}, {0, c}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 1, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 1, 5}, {0, 0, 0, c}}
> ```

Using this, I would rewrite your code as

```
eef = Compile[{{μ, _Real}, {NNN, _Integer}}, 
Module[{}, 

  mm = DiagonalMatrix[MM - B2 k k - B1 (Range[NN] Pi/L)^2];
  {kxm, μM} = {A1 k #, μ #}& @ IdentityMatrix[3];

  kxM =  
   Table[
    If[m == n, 0, 
     (-2 n + (m + n) Cos[(m - n)Pi] + (-m + n) Cos[(m + n) Pi])/((m^2 - n^2)Pi^2),
    {m, NNN}, {n, NNN}
   ];


  HH = ArrayFlatten[{
         {μM + mm, 0, kz, kxM}, 
         {0, μM + mm, kxM, -kz}, 
         {kz, kxM, μM - mm, 0}, 
         {kxM, -kz, 0, μM - mm}
       }];

  ees = Table[Eigenvalues[HH], {k, -.1, .1, .01}]

 ] (* End Module  *)
]  (* End Compile *)
```