# How do I speed up Plot when the independent variable is in the Numerical expression

Tags: plotting

In the following

```
HH = H /. {μ -> 1, Δ -> .3, L -> 11, ky -> 0};
Plot[Re[Sort[Eigenvalues[HH]]], {kx, -2 π/11, 2 π/11}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

where `H` is a matrix expression that depends on `kx, ky, μ, L, Δ`.

Is there a faster way to plot the numerical eigenvalues of this matrix as a function of `kx`, for example? Any help would be really appreciated.

**Update**

I'd like to state, I want to do this purely numerical. My issue is that I want to solve the eigenvalue problem for MANY values of `kx`. H can be large in this case, sometimes 400 by 400. I only used 10 `PlotPoints` just as an example. 
I found that `Table` is very quick and I can do a `ListLinePlot`. I just naively thought this same operation would be done in `Plot`. This is where my confusion still lies if someone wants to help :)

**Second Update**

Here is `H` as requested.

```
NN = 40;
MM = 2 NN + 1;
kM = Table[
      Boole[m == n] (ky + I (kx + m 2 π/L)), 
      {m, -NN, NN, 1}, {n, -NN, NN, 1}];

kM2 = Table[
       Boole[m == n] (ky - I (kx + m 2 π/L)), 
       {m, -NN, NN, 1}, {n, -NN, NN, 1}];

μM = IdentityMatrix[MM] μ;

ΔM = (Δ I/2 ) 
            * Table[ (KroneckerDelta[m, n - 1] - KroneckerDelta[m, n + 1]), 
                     {m, -NN, NN, 1}, {n, -NN, NN, 1}];

H = ArrayFlatten[{
     {-μM, kM,0 μM, ΔM}, 
     {kM2, -μM, -ΔM, 0 μM}, 
     {0 μM, -ΔM, μM, kM2}, 
     {ΔM, 0 μM, kM, μM}
    }];
```

**Third update**
This is initially represented as 
$h= \vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{k}-\mu$

$h_\tau= \vec{\sigma^{\ast}} \cdot \vec{k}+\mu$

$H=\left(\begin{array}{cc} h & i \Delta \sigma_y\\ 
-i \Delta\sigma_y & h_\tau \end{array}\right)$

where $\sigma$ are the Pauli matrices.  The individual values change do to some implications from a physical system. I didn't want to get too deep into the physics, as there is another stack for that.

The block elements don't commute because the Pauli matrices don't commute, but if you see any symmetries that I don't see please do enlighten me. So far I've always done this numerically.

Comment: @R.M Thank you for cleaning this up for me. I'm still trying to get the hang of this.

Comment: Does your matrix possess any special symmetries, such as is it Hermitian?

Comment: @rcollyer It is Hermitian.

Comment: Thanks. Then, `kM == ConjugateTranspose[kM2]`, so you can simplify your code by eliminating `kM2`, and replace it with `kM\[ConjugateTranspose]`. And, as I [pointed out before](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2832/52), you can replace the `0 \[Mu]M` terms with `0`, and it will be interpreted correctly. Any other symmetries that your aware of? If so, you can block-diagonalize it based upon those.

Comment: Here's a [reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=r4GIU2wJCAEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=group+theory+Tinkham&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dBliT9Bz4-LRAZ-t6J8I&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the block-diagonalization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are solving the eigenvalue problem for every point in the plot. If it is feasible to work out the analytical expression for the eigenvalues with `kx` as a symbol, then calculate that outside the plot and plot the solution.

```
HH = H /. {μ -> 1, Δ -> .3, L -> 11, ky -> 0};
eHH=Eigenvalues[HH]]];
Plot[Re[Sort[eHH]], {kx, -2 π/11, 2 π/11}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

You could also try

```
Plot[Re[Sort[Evaluate@Eigenvalues[HH]]], {kx, -2 π/11, 2 π/11}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

But seriously, if you only want ten plot points, precalculate the eigenvalues and then use `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`.

```
eHHlist= With[{HH = H /. {μ -> 1, Δ -> .3, L -> 11, ky -> 0}}, 
 Table[Re[Sort[Eigenvalues[HH]]], {kx, -2 π/11, 2 π/11, 2  π/55}]  ]
ListPlot[eHHlist]
```

Comment: `Evaluate` won't have any effect in that position.  It only does something when you have `Plot[Evaluate[...], ...]`.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing `H`, it's a little difficult to give the best answer, but I think calculating the eigenvalues numerically might speed things up considerably.

My guess is that the eigenvalues get computed symbolically, or at least Mathematica attempts it.  Depending on the matrix, this can produce huge expressions.  This is because `Eigenvalues[HH]` is evaluated before setting a value for `kx`.  This would also prevent `Sort` from sorting by actual numerical values.

So, I recommend that you define a function like this:

```
Clear[hh]
hh[kx_?NumericQ] := Re@Eigenvalues[ (* paste HH here *) ]
```

and plot using

```
Plot[hh[kx], {kx, -2 π/11, 2 π/11}]
```

This should be very fast.  But I can't know for sure that this is the best solution without seeing `H` first.

---

To avoid pasting by hand, you can do the following instead:

```
Clear[HH, hh]

HH[kx_] = H /. {μ -> 1, Δ -> .3, L -> 11, ky -> 0}

hh[kx_?NumericQ] := Re@Eigenvalues[HH[kx]]
```

Note my use of `=` and `:=`.  The distinction is important.